# Sudden failure to boot

Tags: boot, bootloader

I have been using Ubuntu 16.04 for a couple of month without any major problems. Last night after working a bit I suspended it and in the morning xampp server that I was working with was not functioning so I rebooted. But then it didn't boot up with

> platform wdat_wdt: failed to claim resource 4
>   ACPI: watchdog: Device creation failed: -16
>   [Powerplay ] VBIOS did not find boot engine clock value (3 wierd characters) in dependency table. Using memory DPM level 0!
>   /dev/sda6: clean, xxx/xxx files, xxx/xxx blocks

I tried a few guides to no avail and then reinstalled. But the problem still remains!

Furthermore I can boot into system (everything seems to work) if I go to recovery mode and select fcdsk and then after that resume(resume normal boot).

Comment: Probably you have any problem in your hdd. I suggest you check its health by Gnome-disks.

Comment: Do you mean self-test?

Comment: Not exactly that. See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-ssd-or-hdd-on-current-versions-of-ubuntu-1

Comment: The article also says self-test.

Comment: Okay, that's it. What results did you get? I was having problems with my hd that Disks tool was not detecting. It was only a change of the SATA-cable and the problems were gone.

Comment: It's at 30% now and the overall assessment is "Disk is ok, 1080 bad sectors". Could that happen with laptops?

Comment: You are running xampp in your laptop. It's a service that requires processing and huge I/O oprations. It could happen to laptops, too, since they are not builded to feature such operations.

Comment: I wasn't doing much with xampp. Should I worry about bad sectors? Number of uncorrectable bad sectors is zero

Comment: Bad sectors is really bad. I saw many people running after workarounds, as Hiren's Boot or other panacea, but the best remedy to bad sectors, frankly, is a newer HD.

Comment: +1 for the "(3 weird characters)"  it's funny coz I'm looking at them right now like "so, what are these exactly?"